# Plone Workflow Script KeyError

Tags: python, plone, dexterity

I have this workflow script;

```
## parameters = state_change
wf = context.portal_worfklow
catalog = context.portal_catalog
object = state_change.object
path = '/'.join(object.getPhysicalPath())
brains = catalog.searchResults(path={'query':path, 'depth':1}, portal_type='myportaltype', review_state='draft')
if object.TransactionType.lower() == 'sometype':
    for brain in brains:
        obj = brain.getObject()
        wf.doActionFor(obj, 'approve')
```

I want the script to automatically transition from draft into approved on all sub contents of this folder where `portal_type` is equal to `myportaltype`. But I always got an KeyError, it says on the `line => wf.doActionFor(obj,'approve')`. However, I already reviewed
the workflow for `myportaltype` and its next transition is approve. Is there any problem on my code or lacks something?

Comment: Thanks Maz for the revision.

Comment: Mistyped `portal_worflow` for `portal_workflow`?

Comment: Yes, its only typo error. Thanks and already corrected the above code.

Comment: Please provide the full traceback error of the KeyError you got

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have discovered, there was nothing wrong with the codes only that I missed this line of code at the top of the script:

```
##bind context=context
```